# Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()

Tags: java, java-8, sum, java-stream

When you want to sum an integer value from a stream, there are two main ways of doing it:

```
ToIntFunction<...> mapFunc = ...
int sum = stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(mapFunc))

int sum = stream().mapToInt(mapFunc).sum()
```

The first involves boxing the returned integer & unboxing it, but there's an extra step involved in the second.

Which is more efficient/clearer?

Comment: Purely my opinion: the second one is easier to read.

Comment: If you want to know which approach is more efficient benchmark it but the second approach is much clearer to the reader IMHO.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are looking at the intersection of two otherwise distinct use cases. Using `mapToInt(…)` allows you to chain other `IntStream` operations before the terminal operation. In contrast, `Collectors.summingInt(…)` can be combined with other collectors, e.g. used as downstream collector in a `groupingBy` collector. For these use cases, there is no question about which to use.

In your special case, when you are not chaining more operations nor dealing with collectors in the first place, there is no fundamental difference between these two approaches. Still, using the one which is more readable has a point. Usually, you don’t use a collector, when there is a predefined operation on the stream doing the same. You wouldn’t use `collect(Collectors.reducing(…))` when you can just use `.reduce(…)`, would you?

Not only is `mapToInt(mapFunc).sum()` shorted, it also follows the usual left-to-right order for what happens conceptionally, first convert to an `int`, then sum these `int`s up. I think this justifies preferring this alternative over `.collect(Collectors.summingInt(mapFunc))`.

Comment: good idea. what's you said is single interface is simpler than composition here. Am'I right, sir?

Comment: @holi-java: that’s one aspect.

Comment: thanks. your answer let me think of composition is more complicated to use since you must need know how to composes them together, such as: Decorator Design Pattern.