# Difference between summarizingInt and Collectors.summarizingInt?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am working with the IntSummaryStatistics class to calculate out the statistics for my class.
I searched for three particular ways to calculate statistics. Here is my code:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats1 = orderEntries.stream()
            .mapToInt((x) -> x.getAmount()).summaryStatistics();

IntSummaryStatistics stats2 = orderEntries.stream().collect(
            Collectors.summarizingInt(o -> o.getAmount()));

IntSummaryStatistics istats2 = orderEntries.stream().
                            collect( 
                                    () -> new IntSummaryStatistics(),
                                    (i,o) -> i.accept(o.getAmount()),
                                    (i1, i2) -> i1.combine(i2));
IntSummaryStatistics istats = IntStream.of(51,22,50,27,35).
        collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new, IntSummaryStatistics::accept, 
                IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
```

Which one is the better approach? Which one we should prefer over other?

Comment: @Holger The third entry just i got from internet. It is not in sync with orderEnteries.

Comment: Please don't (significantly) change the code your options. I refer to that in my answer and now you've made that reference baseless.

Comment: @lexicore adding that code also.

Comment: See also [“Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37023822/2711488)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd opt to:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = orderEntries
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(OrderEntry::getAmount));
```

This option:

```
IntSummaryStatistics istats = IntStream.of(51,22,50,27,35).
            collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new, IntSummaryStatistics::accept, 
                    IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
```

is the worst, it's exactly what `IntStream.summaryStatistics` does, just written explicitly. So no advantage of the first option.

I'd go with a slightly modified second option because the collector better represents the business operation "summarization of order entry amounts" from my point of view.

Comment: There’s no fundamental difference between `.mapToInt(OrderEntry::getAmount).summaryStatistics()` and `.collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(OrderEntry::getAmount))`. That’s more a matter of taste.

Comment: @lexicore I think collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(OrderEntry::getAmount)) and collect(
            Collectors.summarizingInt(o -> o.getAmount())); are the same. Isn't it?

Comment: @KaranVerma Yes and no. Yes, this will give you the same result. No, in the second case you write out a lambda instead of using an existing method. I'd definitely prefer `OrderEntry::getAmount`. Why writing lambdas if the method is already there?