# When to use specialised stream methods over methods in the Collectors class or vice versa?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

We can see that the [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class contains factory methods for many common aggregation operations. to name a few  `summingXXX`, `averagingXXX`, `maxBy`, `minBy`.

These methods are actually duplicate functionality over calling methods on specialised streams. take for example [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), this has a `sum()`,    `average()` , `max()` and `min()` respectively.

Same goes for [DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) and [LongStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html).

Every now and then I see people using the methods which belong to the Collectors class and specialized stream methods interchangeably.

For example, assuming we have a `List<Employee>` and one wants to get the average salary, you can either use the methods in the specialised primitive streams.

```
OptionalDouble averageUsingIntStream =
             employees.stream()
                      .mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
                      .average();
```

or use the factory methods in the `Collectors` class.

```
Double averageUsingCollectors =
             employees.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Employee::getSalary));
```

Now, my question is what is the motivation behind this duplicate functionality and in which situation is it better to use the first approach or the second?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of “[Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023822/2711488)” to me.

Comment: @Holger while the two questions are similar, that one is asking about which is more efficient and clearer whereas I am asking what’s the motivation behind the duplicate functionality and when one should be used over the other. However, if you still think it’s a dupe then feel free to mark is as a dupe.

Comment: The questions may differ slightly, but in the end, it’s about the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real motivation for the said factory methods in the Collectors class to exist *is to be used as downstream collectors* i.e. a collector that the Java runtime applies to the results of another collector. This enables one to compose together and perform more complex aggregations.

For example, there are [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) collectors that accept a downstream collector, [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-), [partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-), [flatMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) (java-9) et al.

So the rule of thumb is to only use the aforementioned methods in the question as downstream collectors.

The specialised primitive streams are also more efficient so if all you want to do is compute the `sum()`,  `average()` , `max()` or `min()` then I'd stick with the primitive specialisation.

Comment: Please explain what "downstream collectors" are and it will be perfect.

Comment: Did you just ask that question just to answer it immediately?

Comment: @daniu yes that was the intention but anyone is more than welcome to add their own answer and _share the knowledge_.

Comment: It was certainly insightful, just unusual 