# Java 8 Streams | Average words for lines in textfile

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to do some exercise on Streams and encountered following problem:

I have a text file, and I want to compute the average number of words per line. Can someone tell me if my way of thinking is correct? Here's some pseudocode I think should do the trick once implemented:

```
double wordCount(String filepath){
  return Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))
                      // make a wordarray of the line
                      // average the size of every wordarray with something like that
                          (collect(Collectors.averagingDouble())
```

Can someone please help me with that?

How can I convert a line to a String array of words?

How do I get the size of that array?

Comment: Actually you mention several tasks. How to convert a line to an array of Strings. How to get the size of this array. Solve these sub tasks and bring your work to this question.

Comment: *"How do I get the size of that array?"* Really? `arr.length`!!!

Comment: @Andreas Yes I know that's arr. length... Somehow I thought to complicated and didn't think it's that easy with streams...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 steps missing are :

- How can I convert a line to a Stringarray of words : `split` around `spaces` **>>** `s.split(" ");`
- How do I get the size of that array : get its `length` **>>** `arr.length`

---

1. Using specialized operation on `IntStream`

   ```
   double wordCount(String filepath) {
       try {
           return Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))
                   .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                   .mapToInt(arr -> arr.length)
                   .average()
                   .orElse(-1.0);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return -1.0;
   }
   ```
2. Less specific `Collectors` operation ([To avoid againt prop 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965753/when-to-use-specialised-stream-methods-over-methods-in-the-collectors-class-or-v#answers))

   ```
   double wordCount2(String filepath) {
       try {
           return Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))
                   .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                   .map(arr -> arr.length)
                   .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::new));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return -1.0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice, although I'd avoid using the second approach for this specific task. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965753/when-to-use-specialised-stream-methods-over-methods-in-the-collectors-class-or-v

Comment: @azro Thank you very much!

Comment: @Aominè I’d avoid using `String.split` at all, when all I want, is the number of words/matches…

Answer (score 3):

You are doing unnecessary work by splitting a string into a bunch of strings, one for each word, populating an array with them, just to ask for the array’s size afterwards.

If you want to get the number of words, consider a straight-forward method, only counting the words

```
private static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
public static int wordCount(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Matcher m = WORD.matcher(s); m.find(); ) count++;
    return count;
}
```

You may then use this method inside a Stream operation, to get the average word count:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).mapToInt(YourClass::wordCount).average().orElse(0)
```

With Java 9, you could rewrite the `wordCount` method to use a Stream like

```
private static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
public static int wordCount(String s) {
    return (int)WORD.matcher(s).results().count();
}
```

But the loop likely is more efficient as it omits the construction of `MatchResult` instances.

Comment: Nice! , looks compact and elegant.

Comment: @Aominè especially the java-9, a true job for the scanner

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void wordcount(String filePath) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(Paths.get(filePath).toUri());
    double result = Files.lines(path).map(s -> {
        String trimmed = s.trim();
        if (trimmed.isEmpty()) return 0;
        else return trimmed.split(" ").length;
    }).mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).average().getAsDouble();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```