# Difference between stream.max(Comparator) and stream.collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator) in Java

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

In Java Streams - what is the difference between `stream.max(Comparator)` and `stream.collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator))` in terms of performance. Both will fetch the max based on the comparator being passed. If this is the case, why do we need the additional step of collecting using the `collect` method? When should we choose former vs latter? What are the use case scenarios suited for using both?

Answer (score 12):

They do the same thing, and share the same code.

> why do we need the additional step of collecting using the collect method?

You don't. Use `max()` if that's what you want to do. But there are cases where a Collector can be handy. For example:

```
Optional<Foo> result = stream.collect(createCollector());
```

where `createCollector()` would return a collector based on some condition, which could be maxBy, minBy, or something else.

In general, you shouldn't care too much about the small performance differences that might exist between two methods that do the same thing, and have a huge chance of being implemented the same way. Instead, you should make your code as clear and readable as possible.

Comment: Looks like a variation of [Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023822/2711488)…

Answer (score 7):

There is a relevant quote in *Effective Java* 3rd Edition, page 214:

> The collectors returned by the `counting` method are intended *only* for use as downstream collectors. The same functionality is available directly on `Stream`, via the `count` method, so **there is never a reason to say `collect(counting())`**. There are fifteen more `Collectors` with this property.

Given that `maxBy` is duplicated by `Stream.max`, it is presumably one of these sixteen methods.

Shortly after, same page, it goes on to justify the dual existence:

> From a design perspective, these collectors represent an attempt to partially duplicate the functionality of streams in collectors so that downstream collectors can act as "ministreams".

Personally, I find this edict and explanation a bit unsatisfying: it says that it wasn't the *intent* for these 16 collectors to be used like this, but not why they *shouldn't*.

I suppose that the methods directly on stream are able to be implemented in specialized ways which could be more efficient than the general collectors.

Comment: I may actually be incorrectly inferring that `maxBy` is one of the downstream 16, as the final paragraph on the page does mention it explicitly as one of three collectors not yet mentioned. I find this part of this item unusually unclear for EJ.

Comment: So if say we use a 'parallelStream' instead of linear Stream the functions such as finding 'max' - does it improves on performance?.  Does this have any implication on the above two approaches? Reading more on streams why so many different approaches and what is suited where..

Answer (score 0):

According to java Documentation ,

the below are definition for maxBy , minBy From Collectors class ,

```
static <T> Collector<T,?,Optional<T>> maxBy(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Returns a Collector that produces the maximal element according to a given Comparator, described as an `Optional<T>`.

```
static <T> Collector<T,?,Optional<T>> minBy(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Returns a Collector that produces the minimal element according to a given Comparator, described as an `Optional<T>`.

where as `max()` and `min()` in `Stream` return the `Optional<T>`

every stream pipeline operation can be divided into terminal and non terminal operation .
so by definition from java doc , it is one thing clear that Stream provided `max()` ,`min()` are terminal operation and return `Optional<T>` .

but the `maxBy()` and `minBy()` are Collector producing operation , so they can be used for chaining computation .

Answer (score 0):

They both use `BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparator)` and do a `reducing` operation to the elements (even though the implementation of how it is reduced is slightly different). Hence there are no changes in the output.

If you need to find the max among all the stream elements, I suggest using `Stream.max` because the code would look neat and also you do not really need to create a collector in this case.

But there are scenarios where `Collectors.maxBy` need to be used. Assume that you need to group your elements and need to find the max in each group. In such scenarios you cannot use `Stream.max`. Here you need to use `Collectors.groupingBy(mapper, Collectors.maxBy(...))`. Similarly you could use it for `partitionBy` and other similar methods where you need a collector.