# Java 8 Stream API min() and max() vs Collectors minBy() and maxBy()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

In java 8 , Stream API help us to do our job with very clean and with less number of code. I am big fan of these stream API. But there are few operations which kind of help in solving the same type of problem and not sure when to use which operations Although it is not that much hard to choose between but just want to know any one have any specific use case for these. Operation which i am talking about is :-

Intermediate Operations :- `min` and `max`

Terminal Operation: `collect` with `Collectors` class strategy using `minBy` and `maxBy`

```
List<String> randomString= Arrays.asList("AA","AAA","A","AAAA","AAAAAA","AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
String maxByIntermediateMax = randomString.stream().max(String :: compareTo).get();
String minByIntermediateMin = randomString.stream().min(String :: compareTo).get();
System.out.println("Intermediate Min() :- "+minByIntermediateMin+" Intermeidate Max() :- "+ maxByIntermediateMax);
String minByCollectorsMinBy = randomString.stream().collect(Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())).get();
String maxByCollectorsMaxBy = randomString.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())).get();
System.out.println("Collectors MinBy :- "+minByCollectorsMinBy+ " , Collectors maxBy is :- "+maxByCollectorsMaxBy);
```

**Output**

```
Intermediate Min() :- A Intermeidate Max() :- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Collectors MinBy :- A , Collectors maxBy is :- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Basically the same consideration as in [Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37025002/2711488) By the way, there is no need to create a new comparator via `String :: compareTo` when you already know about `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: ... at least unless there are any performance benefits that one can prove.

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc of `Stream#min` says that `min` is a **terminal operation**, so `.collect(Collectors.minBy(...))` and `.min(...)` are interchangeable.

As for me, `min` and `max` have more readable syntax, but `collect` is more generic, so as an example, you can pass min/max collector as an argument of your method.

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.min` and `Stream.max` are **terminal** operations. The javadoc clearly states that.

The similarity between these two is what you have mentioned in your question. They both, using `BinaryOperator.minBy(comparator)` do a `reducing` operation to the elements (even though the implementation of how it is reduced is slightly different).

Hence there are no changes in output in your code. Since you need to find the min/max among all the stream elements, I would suggest using `Stream.min` for your case because the code would look neat and also you do not really need to create a collector in this case.

But there are scenarios where `Collectors.minBy` need to be used. Assume that you need to group your elements and need to find the min/max in each group. In such scenarios you cannot use `Stream.min`. Here you need to use `Collectors.groupingBy(mapper, Collectors.minBy(...))`. Similarly you could use it for `partitionBy` and other similar methods where you need a collector.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stream().max` effectively produces the same result as `stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy)`.
The same is true for `stream().min` and `stream().collect(Collectors.minBy)`

While the results are the same, there are some subtle differences on the readability and flexibility offered from these 2 approaches.

By using Collectors you can use any collector returning an `Optional<String>`. The implemented`min` and `max` are just some implemented versions of [Collectors.reducing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). You could also use any other `Collector`similar to [Collectors.reducing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) as an argument.

```
 List<String> randomString= Arrays.asList("AA","AAA","A","AAAA","AAAAAA","AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
 Collector<String, ?, Optional<String>> collectorMin = Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder());
 Collector<String, ?, Optional<String>> collectorMax = Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    
     
    String collectedMin= randomString.stream().collect(collectorMin ).get();
    String collectedMax= randomString.stream().collect(collectorMax ).get();
```

On the other hand `stream().max`/`stream().min` are much more readable and less verbose.