# What is the difference between Stream.count() vs Collectors.counting()

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

Are there any differences between the `count()` method in the `Stream` interface vs `counting()` in `Collectors`? Which one should one use in general? Are there any performance benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: I don't know about performance, but to me, the most important difference is that collectors can be used as the downstream of other collectors. You can use `counting` (but not `count`) as the downstream of `groupingBy` or `mapping`, for example.

Comment: We had [min() and max() vs Collectors minBy() and maxBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67998785/2711488) just yesterday. We don’t need a new question for every “collector vs terminal operation”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023822/collectors-summingint-vs-maptoint-sum)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to count (all) [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) elements use `count()`

> Returns the count of elements in this stream. This is a special case of a reduction and is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
> ```

Use [counting()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8) when you need the count to be grouped, as:

> ```
> Map<String, Long> collect = 
>    wordsList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
> ```

Answer (score 11):

One difference is with the implementation. This is documented on `Stream.count()` (at least on versions 9+):

> An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated...

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .map(i -> {
            System.out.println("processing " + i);
            return i * 2;
        }).count());

System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .map(i -> {
            System.out.println("processing " + i);
            return i * 2;
        }).collect(Collectors.counting()));
```

Both will give you the correct count, but the first one may skip the execution of `map()`, thus might not show `println`'s output. As documented, this is implementation detail (`count()` may skip intermediate operations if it can determine the number of elements without executing the pipeline)

Comment: @user7294900 as documented, it's implementation-related. Spec says *may*. On mine, it skips the `map` operation. The bottom line is that the developer should not count on count() causing all operations before it to run.

Comment: @user7294900 What Java version and distribution are you using?

Comment: Java 8 Oracle distribution

Comment: @user7294900 OpenJDK 8 too gives the output. But OpenJDK 11 seems to be optimized. I suspect even Oracle JDK 11 would be.